# JavaScript cannot see declared variable?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a C# aspx page with this declaration:

```html
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Samples (Lab)" OnClientClick="toggleLab(); return false;" />&nbsp;
```

The `toggleLab` function is described in the document script section and is called just fine. In the same script section, before the functions, a global is defined, so the code is like this:

```js
var samplesOff; 

function toggleLab() {
    console.log("toggleLab, samplesOff: ", samplesOff);
    ...
}
```

`samplesOff` is accessible from other function called after the `onLoad` event. However, when I press the button, the JavaScript function does not know about samplesOff variable.

What can I do to reach the variable from the function called from `onClientClick` in C# button? Why isn't my variable accessible during the call?

Comment: It should be accessible, why do you think it is not? My guess is that the `onload` function redeclares it and does not assign to the global variable, but a local one - to `toggleLab` the global is still `undefined`

Comment: what makes you think it is not accessible? have you tried concatenation rather than the `,` ? i.e. `"....samplesOff: " + samplesOff` ?

Comment: What does the other function (called after onload) look like? What does the generated HTML look like (the ASP is irrelevant unless it isn't generating the HTML you want, in which case that should be the focus of the question)?

Comment: Can we please see the `onLoad` handler?

Comment: It should be accessible. You can cross check by assigning some  value to the global variable like "var samplesOff= 'some value';". And check if this value is there in button click event.

Comment: Yes, redefinition of it inside onLoad (I forgot to add "var" before initilalization of samplesOff in the onLoad) was the problem. Now it is defined. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think console.log does not accept the subtitution parameters in all browsers:

You can check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log, basically what it says is that not all the browsers supports substitution strings.